# Azure and the old .Net remoting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, remoting, azure-virtual-network

By .Net remoting I mean the 10 year old predecessor to WCF

Does Azure support it? I assume it does inside a VM but for VM to VM communication? What about from an App Service to a VM?

I appreciate it's not the most heavily used of technologies these days, the name is a little difficult to Google on as remoting is a fairly common phrase

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can run an app on App Service which leverages .Net Remoting as long as it communicates over TCP or HTTP.  You'll have to validate your app runs on the .Net framework versions installed (currently 3.5 and 4.7)